# PHP if statement return me true but it should be false

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

Hello i have Laravel application, and on my blade view if there is a difference between 2 data i add background color, but both value are equal to 0 (int) so it should not happen.

```
<tr 
     @if($prod->status!=$tmp->status)
         style="background:red"
     @endif
 >
```

when i dump status data i have this :

```
dump($prod->status, $tmp->status);
// display 0, 0
```

Both of them are ***int*** even if i add "***!==***" same things happen.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue https://fiddle.nette.org/blade/#14d7a864ef, please update your question with the results from `var_dump($prod->status, $tmp->status);` including the int/string, value.

Answer (score 0):

On the prod and temp status, if you have a value of 0 then it won't apply style as per your logic. Your condition value needs to be different.

please check the example in the following link
[here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/efedf12e-66eb-4257-9dfa-9e4641d98750)